# Save binary file to blob from httppostedfile

Tags: file-upload, azure, binary, blob

Can somebody provide code to save an uploaded file to azure blob in binary? I currently use a text save which is incredibly slow on huge files, reading/saving to blob, line by line.

```
Private Function ReadFile(ByVal file As HttpPostedFile) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(file.InputStream)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            result = result & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
        Loop
        Return result
    End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This code fragment is based on a production app that pushes photos into blob storage. This approach pulls the stream directly from the HttpPostedFile and hands it directly to the client library for storing into a blob. You should vary a few things based on your application:

- blobName will likely need to adapted.
- The connectionstring up to fetching the blob client should be isolated into helper classes
- Similarly you will likely want a helper for the blob container based on your business logic
- You may not want the container to be fully publicly accessible. That was just added to show you how to do that if you like

```cs
// assuming HttpPostedFile is in a variable called postedFile  
var contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
var streamContents = postedFile.InputStream;
var blobName = postedFile.FileName

var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("YOURSTORAGEACCOUNT_CONNECTIONSTRING");
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("YOURCONTAINERNAME");
container.CreateIfNotExist();
container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

var blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
blob.UploadFromStream(streamContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

6 years later it seems [Dennis Burton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168720/dennis-burton) answer isn't compatible with WindowsAzure.Storage v9.3.2.

For me this works:

```
IFormFile postedFile = null;
var contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
var blobName = postedFile.FileName;

var connectionString = "YOURSTORAGEACCOUNT_CONNECTIONSTRING";
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("YOURCONTAINERNAME");
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
using (var streamContents = postedFile.OpenReadStream())
{
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(streamContents);
}
```